# Visual C++ - Unable to get Text value of listBox item, error C2872: 'Text' : ambiguous symbol

Tags: text, listbox, c++-cli

```
myWarcraftRace->removeSkill( sysStringToCharArray( listBox_mySkills->SelectedItem->Text ) );
```

syStringToCharArray() does work, also the removeSkill() does work, problem is that I can't get the Text value of listBox_mySkills->SelectedItem

If I do as I did above, it gives me error:

```
1>d:\programming\vc++ projects\wcrace maker\MainForm.h(194): error C2872: 'Text' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'System::Drawing::Text'
1>          or       'System::Text'
1>d:\programming\vc++ projects\wcrace maker\MainForm.h(194): error C2882: 'Text' : illegal use of namespace identifier in expression
```

And if I'll try to use it without text, it gives me error:

```
1>d:\programming\vc++ projects\wcrace maker\MainForm.h(194): error C2664: 'sysStringToCharArray' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Object ^' to 'System::String ^'
```

Which it obliviously is supposed to do, cause sysStringToCharArray() takes System::String^ parameter. So Problem is that I'm unable to use the Text property of the listbox item, anyone have any ideas why's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting a great error message here.  The *real* problem is the type of the ListBox::SelectedItem property.  It is Object, a listbox can store any kind of value or object.  And Object doesn't have a Text property.  The compiler now goes noddy when hunting for the "Text" identifier and finding a match in namespace names, more than one.  Fix:

```
listBox_mySkills->SelectedItem->ToString()
```

Comment: Hmmh, no longer gives an error, but skill still doesn't get removed. If I manually type the name of the selecteditem, it then does, so the problem is still at getting the selected listbox item... =/

Comment: Edit: Nvm, had a typo :'D Thanks, that works, and +1 for explaining why it's supposed to be like that, for once I actually understood the fix :D